# Hacer mayúscula la primera letra de un string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Obtengo el valor del mes actual desde el `DateTime.Now.Month`

```
  CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
  ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
  var mes = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", ci);
```

resultado de variable mes: marzo

Lo que quiero hacer es realizar la primera letra en mayúscula es decir "Marzo", como puedo lograr esto?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
var mes = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", ci);
Console.WriteLine(mes);
TextInfo textInfo = ci.TextInfo;    
Console.WriteLine(textInfo.ToTitleCase(mes));
```

Resultado:

```
marzo
Marzo
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes intentar de esta forma:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
var mes = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", ci);
mes = mes.substring(0, 1).toUpper() + mes.substring(1).toLower();
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes trabajar con cualquier función de uppercase. Como por ejemplo:

```
public static string FirstCharToUpper(string input)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        case null: throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        case "": throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(input)} cannot be empty", nameof(input));
        default: return input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + input.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

Y aplicarlo a tu mes; ya que tu var mes es un string.

```
 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
  ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
  var mes = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", ci);
  var Mes = FirstCharToUpper(mes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Extensores
{
    public static string FirstCharToUpper(this Object objeto)
    {
        try
        {
            string input = objeto.ToString().ToLower() ?? throw new Exception();
            return input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + input.Substring(1);
        }
        catch { return string.Empty; }
    }
 }
```

Aplicas:

```
var item = "tu string aqui".FirstCharToUpper();
```

**Basado en la respuesta de farsSharp**